# XCode 7 - import private Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, import, frameworks, xcode7

Recently I encountered a little problem in my project (I'm making Framework). I wanted to import to my project Framework - https://github.com/dparnell/swift-parser-generator .

At first, I saw bunch od pro tips about adding this framework to Embdedded Binaries, turning embedded [...] in Swift to Yes etc. And the first problem - there is no Embedded Binaries if u want to build Framework ( Framework Target ).

So I searched where it can be and I found that a simple app (Cocoa for OS X and I think Single Page View for iOS) has the Embedded Binaries. So I dragged Product - SwiftParser.framework to Embedded Binaries and after a while it worked.

But! This is not my target. So I need to start where I begun but I have no idea where to start searching the answer so that's why I'm asking you guys for help.

Thank up front,

James